# responseType for Angular HttpClient that can be either a blob or JSON

Tags: angular

I have a REST API that returns either:

1. binary data as a blob; or
2. JSON data when there's an error.

The first scenario works with `responseType: 'blob'` and the second works with `responseType: 'json'`.

Can I somehow set the `responseType` after getting the response (i.e. depends on HTTP status code, etc.).

Comment: Why don't you modify your API and send only one responseType? For example you could send only JSON which would have a encoded blob. "file": encodedBlob

Answer (score 1):

You can not.

P.S. Same REST API method returns blob either json? really? Probably you can distinguish at frontend somehow, by some argument value or so and set 'responseType' accordingly.

Or always expect blob then try to parse it with filereader and check if there is JSON inside.

Or implement interceptor. You can adjust response headers and content then.

Comment: Really - normal response blob. error comes back as json. Parsing the blob with FileReader works (I am using that now). I up voted this answer but not assigning as "correct answer" as it seems like a workaround.